# why is apache virtual server is not running

Tags: apache, laravel, ubuntu, localhost, virtual-server

I'm trying to make a virtual server on my apache server to work with a laravel application:

I made a conf file name "brk.localhost.conf" with the following contents:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin admin@example.com
   ServerName brk.localhost
   ServerAlias www.brk.localhost
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/brokers/public
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

ran these commands:

```
sudo a2ensite brk.localhost.conf

service apache2 reload

sudo service apache2 restart
```

but still when I'm trying to go to "www.brk.localhost" I get:

> Server not found

I tried to replace the port number 80 with "brk.localhost" but still not working.

Comment: You'd need to add an entry to the hosts file so the browser knows where to look for `www.brk.localhost`.

Comment: sorry i'm new to this, where is the hosts file?

Comment: great got it , thanks... write an answer so I can vote for it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to add an entry to the hosts file so the browser knows where to look for `www.brk.localhost`.

The fastest way to find out how to edit the hosts file on your specific system is to Google `how to edit hosts file <name of your operating system>`.

Comment: yeah, that's what i did :)